# having problems connecting to sybase using quarkus with vert.x jdbc client

Tags: quarkus, vert.x

finally I am starting to migrate some monolith code to quarkus/vert.x reactive services.

I am starting simple with a small service connecting to an exsiting DB. our DB currently is sybase (asa which is a relational one and IQ which is a column based DB).

I am trying to work with vert.x reactive jdbc client which I understand is generic to all jdbc supporting DBs (as quarkus built in reactive jdbc does not support sybase).
no luck until now, I mange to get a connection but when executing a query against the DB and ONLY if there is data in the table I get the following error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybResultSet does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object getObject(int, java.lang.Class)' of interface java.sql.ResultSet.
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getObject(NewProxyResultSet.java:217)
    at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.spi.impl.JDBCDecoderImpl.lambda$parse$0(JDBCDecoderImpl.java:60)
```

googling this error did not help much.
please note I am in no way shape of form an expert in any of the stacks I reffer to. this is almost my first try in these type of things.
I would appreciate any help regarding this matter...
thanks!

BTW, my related gradle dependencies in my quarkus projects are:

```
    implementation 'io.vertx:vertx-jdbc-client'
implementation 'io.agroal:agroal-pool:1.16'
implementation files('lib/jconn3.jar')
```

I inject vert.x in my quarkus service and use it to create the connection pool.
Also, I tried both vert.x jdbc client approches (sqlclient and jdbc client) and they both end up in the same exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like upgrade from jconn3 driver to jconn4 driver AND only using the jdbc client approach (now depracated) worked for me...
thanks

update: there's a jconn42.jar driver which is a jdbc4.2 implementation.
the LogUtils class inside calls a method that is not allowed by the jboss logging system so quarkus/wildfly will fail right away using this newer driver.

the method call is to 'logger.setParent(SybDriver.getLogger());' and in the jboss logging system it throws a security exception...

after decompiling and commenting out the problematic line the driver will work but still, only with the legacy jdbcclient aproach and not the new sql client approach...
hope this will help some people stuck with sybase databases...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).